# Need help to understand this weird bahaviour of go routines

Tags: go, goroutine

I've following code using go routines:

```
package main

import  ( 
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func thread_1(i int)    {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    fmt.Println("thread_1: i: ",i)
}   

func thread_2(i int)    {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    fmt.Println("thread_2: i: ",i)
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++    {
        go thread_1(i)
        go thread_2(i)
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

I was expecting each go routine would wait for a second and then print its value of i.

However, both the go routines waited for 1 second each and printed all the values of i at once.

Another question in the same context is:
I've a server-client application where server spawns a receiver go routine to receive data from client one for each client connection. Then the receiver go routine spawns a worker go routine called processor to process the data. There could be multiple receiver go routines and hence multiple processor go routines.
In such a case some receiver and processor go routines may hog indefinitely.

Please help me understand this behaviour.

Comment: You have to understand that the statement `go thread_1()` returns immediately, so all of your goroutines are created in a really short time, so all of the 200 Sleep calls will return almost at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You span 100 goroutines running thread_1 and 100 goroutines running thread_2 in one big batch. Each of these 200 goroutines sleeps for one second and then prints and ends. So yes, the behavior is to be expected: 200 goroutines sleeping each 1 second in parallel and then 200 goroutines printing in parallel.

(And I do not understand your second question)